# rpm signing error rpmMkTemp failed

Tags: linux, centos, gnupg, packages, rpm

I'm running into this error when signing an rpm file. I've not got a whole lot to go on as you can see, and google seems to have come up empty. I'm stumped !

Does anyone know what causes it ? I'm guessing it's trying to make some sort of temp file... somewhere.

```
$: rpm -D "_gpg_name rpmbuilder" --addsign outputs/sllop-0.0.6-1.x86_64.rpm --verbose --debug
Enter pass phrase: 
Pass phrase is good.
outputs/sllop-0.0.6-1.x86_64.rpm:
D: Expected size:        51827 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(51547)
D:   Actual size:        51827
D: GPG sig size: 72
D: Got 72 bytes of GPG sig
D: GPG sig size: 72
D: Got 72 bytes of GPG sig
error: rpmMkTemp failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self answering this in-case anyone else gets confused by this.

This error message turned out to be a little misleading. It was indeed a permissions issue (as expected) but not on any of the tmp dirs related to the rpm variables.

Using strace with

```
strace -p `ps --no-headers -fC rpmsign | awk '{print $2}'` -e trace=open,close
```

Strace showed that after all the work inside the tmp dir (/var/tmp in this case) that it then tried to make an altered version of the rpm in the same dir as the rpm, before (i assume) moving it into place. *That* rpm was the 'temporary' it referred to.

So after all that, it turns out this user just didn't have write permissions to where the rpm was located when being signed.

Ugh.

Comment: Ugh indeed. thanks for this answer, I just wish the error messages were less cryptic.